# Header or footer hidden when open the keyboard in IOS using ionic3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3

Whenever I am going to enter data to textarea field that time I am not able to sea header in ios.

[image]

At a time I am able to view header or footer.

[image]

[image]

Header Hidden when open the keyboard & Footer Hidden

Expected Behaviour: We need to display header and footer when I typing message

```
Ionic:
```

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, (and 24 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   NodeJS     : v10.1.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.1.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255

Comment: possible you may fixed the position so it is overlapping or else use `margin-top` for the key board, you problem will be solve

Answer (score 0):

This would be related to **cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard** plugin.

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/blob/master/README.md

Please check for the sections **KeyboardResize** and **KeyboardResizeMode** and use appropriate values.

Comment: I used KeyboardResize and KeyboardResizeMode but still is not resolved